# Ubuntu USB boot not working

Tags: boot, live-usb, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04. I put it on an USB stick because my netbook does not have an optical drive and when I put it in it boots right back to Windows. I set it to boot to USB and I do not know if I need to download any additional software for it to be seen.

Answer (score 1):

Check the boot menu for sequence of bootable partition.

- Power On your computer
- Press the Boot Menu Key, usually Esc or F12 when the display starts

  [image: Image for BIOS menu]
- select boot menu

  [image: Image for boot menu]
- Select USB-HDD

Answer (score 0):

Did you make your USB bootable? if not check this out: [bootable usb](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: I just downloaded Ubuntu again then followed the process shown and none of Ubuntu versions were shown and when I selected Ubuntu it would not allow me to convert it. Any recommendations

Comment: so you did download universal usb installer? - and then what is your problem exactly? - at step 1 you should almost 100% see ubuntu versions - because it is only to specify wich version of ubuntu you downloaded and going to mount. and the other steps should not raise an issue neither. please specify